# Imposing extra filters on a new added column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have `df` and I can generate new column `varA` without any problem like below.

```
df <- tribble(
  ~Gender, ~Age, ~x, ~y, ~z,
  1, 15, 1, 1, 0, 
  1, 14, 1, 1, 1, 
  2, 12, 0, 0, 1, 
  1, 18, 1, 0, 0, 
  2, 19, 0, 0, 0, 
  2, 22, 1, 0, 1,
  1, 11, 0, 1, 1, 
  1, 13, 1, 1, 1, 
  2, 10, 1, 0, 1,
)

df$varA <- ifelse(rowSums(df[c("x", "y", "z")] == 1) > 1, 1, 0)
```

But what I want is to have the `varA` based on two conditions: 1) only for gender category 1, 2) only for those between 10-14 (inclusive). I try **dplyr** verbs but I ran to a problem.

```
df <- df %>%
  filter(Gender == 1 & Age > 9 & Age < 15) %>%
  mutate(
    varA = ifelse(rowSums(df[c("x", "y", "z")] == 1) > 1, 1, 0)
  )
```

Also, I would appreciate if one could suggest any **base R** way to this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
df$varA <- ifelse(df$Gender == 1 &                        # 1st condition
                  df$Age >= 10 & df$Age <= 14 &           # 2nd condition
                  rowSums(df[c("x", "y", "z")] == 1) > 1, # 3rd condition
                  1, 0)
```

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    varA = ifelse(Gender == 1 &
                  Age >= 10 & Age <= 14 &  
                  # or: between(Age, 10, 14) & (thxs to zephryl)
                  rowSums(across(c("x", "y", "z"), ~.x == 1)) > 1,
                  1, 0)
  )
```

Comment: The dplyr solution could also use `between(Age, 10, 14)` for the second condition.